# Simplest way for getting my own playlists from Spotify API?

Tags: api, spotify, playlist

What I want to accomplish:
**Display all my Spotify playlist on my website and let my visitors play the songs.**

From what I've understood, I need to use the Spotify Web API to accomplish that, so I registered an app and received a Client Id and a Client Secret.

All the examples I've seen on https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/ are pretty advanced for a newbie like myself and they all seem to require stuff like node.js or Composer etc. which I can't install since I'm on a shared hosting service.

What's the easiest way to show my playlists on my website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure all your playlists are publicly available (users other than you can't read your private playlists) and call the following endpoint — everything you need to know is documented:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/